# Resolving inital Grails dependencies with an internal artifact mirror and user credentials

Tags: grails, dependencies, installation

When calling the 'grails' command for the first time in the console, it is trying to resolve additional dependencies via the internet. However due to our corporate firewall we can only access those via an internal Artifactory respository that is supposed to act as a mirror. The repository is protected by username and password.

According to the Grails Documentation you can force Grails in the *%GRAILS_HOME%\settings.groovy* file to look for dependencies at a specific URL. However at the moment it is not possible to add credentials to that (see: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10013).

**Is there any other way to automatically resolve all initial Grails dependencies with an internal artifact repository and credentials?**

Note: I'm talking about the general Grails level, not the grails.project level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: This issue has been fixed with Grails 3.2; It now works like a charm. No more workarounds needed.